# How can I run php artisan serve using .env.production?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Web Application, and it works just fine locally, using a local `.env` file that references the local database.

I have the same Laravel Web Application deployed in production, where I find a `.env`, which is different from the one that I use locally.

Both the scenarios work perfectly, but when I wanted to perform a test with the remote database (that I can access from my local IP address), I copied the remote `.env` and renamed it `.env.production`.

How can I run the `php artisan serve` using the `.env.production` ?

The `php artisan serve` help states that adding a `--env` parameter should make the trick, as you can see from the command result below

```
php artisan serve --help
Description:
  Serve the application on the PHP development server

Usage:
  serve [options]

Options:
      --host[=HOST]     The host address to serve the application on [default: "127.0.0.1"]
      --port[=PORT]     The port to serve the application on
      --tries[=TRIES]   The max number of ports to attempt to serve from [default: 10]
      --no-reload       Do not reload the development server on .env file changes
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

but the command `php artisan serve --env=production` still loads the local database.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This doesn't seem right... The way you have the command now, using `--env=production` should load `.env.production`. I have this command aliased: `php artisan serve --env=testing --port=8080`, which boots a new instance of `localhost:8080` using `.env.test`. Your answer below doesn't look right, but maybe it's a version-specific thing? (didn't downvote, by the way)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for not downvoting ! I wish it worked, but sadly it does not. Version is `Laravel Framework 8.25.0` , the latest available, and the only way I managed to use the `.env.production` is the one in my answer... I don't like it either, trust me ! Does your aliased command actually work ?

Comment: No problem! So my Laravel version is Laravel 6.x, so that _might_ have something to do with it, but I haven't worked with Laravel 8 yet, so can't say for certain. And yes, that command ran standalone or via a `.zsh` alias works; it uses the values in `.env.test`, primarily `DB_` values for setting up a feature/unit testing database. Hopefully someone else is able to verify. Cheers!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After some tests I found a working solution in a [Laracast Forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/artisan-serve-running-wrong-env), giving credits to a [Laravel.io post](https://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2014-testing-artisan-server-environment-setting) that consists into running the following command:

```
APP_ENV=production php artisan serve
```

This causes the `.env.production` to be loaded and used by the local server, as needed.

I post this here hoping it will be useful to someone in my same condition.